# Setting up ads (Google Adsense) on my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, adsense

so, it's been around 4-5 months since I created my wordpress website and I applied for Google Adsense like 2 months ago and I got accepted after a week or two (DİDN'T ADD THE ADS YET). So now the question is, I get around 20-30 visitors everyday (some days it can be less or more), so are these numbers too less in order to activate ads on my website and what if I did activate the ads on my website, so, can google reject/deactivate my Adsense account for having less visitors?
I'm confused here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your site is accepted on Google Adsense, you can add the ad code to your website. It is not common for Adsense to deactivate your website if you don't have a lot of visitors, however the less visitors you have, the lower are your potential earnings.